# Is there a way to add a new VC mode for a different tool?

Tags: version-control

I'm new to this forum and using VC in emacs so if this question has been answered or is just very basic, I apologize. At my employer we use a Version Control system that is not one of the systems supported by emacs. I was hoping there was a way to add a new mode. Presently I have all the commands as aliases in my .cshrc but would like to know if there is a way to integrate the system with emacs.

Comment: Your question is very vague to give an answer. What's the name of your version control system?

Comment: Yes, you can. Read the commentary in `vc.el`. There are, of course, many supported backend libraries which you can read to learn implementation details.

Comment: Hi theldoria, thanks for the response. I didn't mention the VC system but I guess I should have. It is called DesignSync(forgot the manufacture name) and commonly used with Cadence design tools for semiconductor design. We have started using it with our code as well.

Comment: Thanks phils! I didn't know which file to look at. I was original looking at something called version.el and that wasn't helping. :-) Off to read the correct file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, VC is structured so as to be easy to add new backends.  The main code is in `vc.el`, and then each backend has a `vc-<backend>.el` file.
Check all the `vc-<backend>.el` provided with Emacs to see what is needed.  Basically, you'll want to start by defining a `vc-<backend>-registered` function which returns non-nil if the file is under control of `<backend>`.  And you'll want to add your `<backend>` to `vc-handled-backends`.  Then errors will popup whenever a `vc-<backend>-<operation>` function is needed.  And that `<operation>` is described at the beginning of `vc.el`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! More good information. Since I used to use CVS I'll start by reading that vc-cvs.el and see if I can mimic the same functions. Appreciate the pointer to the backend files!